# Cannot set property 'postscribe' of null

Tags: jquery, google-ads-api, adsense

When I am calling "postscribe" then it's showing that:

```
Cannot set property 'postscribe' of null.
```

My code is

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function () {   
     google_ad_client = "pub-9999999999999999";
     google_ad_slot = "9999999999";
     google_ad_width = 300;
     google_ad_height = 250;
     postscribe('#adv1', '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"><\\/script>');
})
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

this error means that the element (`#adv1`) you gave to postscribe does not exist in the DOM at the time your script was run.

Before running your script, first add the `#adv1` to the DOM. You could do something like this:

```
$("body").append("<div id='adv1'>")
postscribe('#adv1', '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"><\\/script>');
```